# Multiplication operator has no eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let $X=C([0,1])$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,1].$

Consider $T:X\rightarrow X$ given by $(Tf)(t)=tf(t).$

Then $T$ has no eigenvalues.

My thought :

Assume that $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Then, $Tf=\lambda f$  for a non-zero $f$

So we have $(t-\lambda )f(t)=0$

Then, $t=\lambda\in[0,1]$

Then, my friend told me that if $ t \neq \lambda$, then $f=0$

And $f$ is continuous, so it forces $f$ to be zero.

But I don't quite understand his argument since $t \in [0,1]$.

So can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Also, I have found similar posts.

http://planetmath.org/exampleofboundedoperatorwithnoeigenvalues

[Multiplication operator has no no eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770915/multiplication-operator-has-no-no-eigenvalues)

But unfortunately, I failed to understand them, so I'm asking here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(t-\lambda)f(t)=0$, this implies that if $t\neq\lambda$, $f(t)=0$. If $f=0$ on $[0,1]-\{\lambda\}$ then $f=0$ on $[0,1]$ take $x_n$ such that $lim_nx_n=\lambda$ and $x_n\neq\lambda$, $f(\lambda)=lim_nf(x_n)=0$ since $f$ is continuous.